# Change layout background in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Although I used to change the background with the code below, but now the program crashes

```
binding.cardLAYOUT.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.gift_card_100);
```

or

```
binding.cardLAYOUT.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gift_card_1));
```

I did not change anything, the images and codes are the same as before

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cardLAYOUT"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gift_card_13"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="100:60"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline32">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by moving the png files to the drawable-xxxhdpi directory

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been using android:src = "@mipmap/your_picture" to insert a picture. I know that you're trying to set a background, but if your background is .png, you should save it in mipmap.mdpi in stead of drawable. Maybe that's why ur programm crashes.